# Need Help: Fortran Infinite Loop

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm very new to using Fortran, and I can't seem to figure out why this subroutine is getting stuck in an infinite loop. Here's the code for said DO loop:

```
SUBROUTINE FILLARRAY(K, N)
    REAL X, Y
    INTEGER XPOS, YPOS
    INTEGER K(N,N)

    DO 10 I = 1, 100
15  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(X)
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(Y)
    XPOS = 20 * X + 1.0
    YPOS = 20 * Y + 1.0
    PRINT *, XPOS
    PRINT *, YPOS
    IF(K(XPOS, YPOS).NE.1) THEN
        K(XPOS,YPOS) = 1
    END IF
    IF (K(XPOS, YPOS).EQ.1) THEN
        GOTO 15
    END IF
10  CONTINUE
    RETURN 
    END
```

I am basically trying to fill a 20 x 20 array randomly with the value 1.

I was also wondering if there is a way to forego using END IF that anyone knows about! Thank you!

Comment: If you are new to Fortran, try learning it from some modern resources. Use indentation, avoid `GO TO`, use modern `==` and `/=` operator forms, `IMPLICIT NONE` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The array will eventually all be set to `1` leading to an infinte loop with `GOTO 15`.

Try this code instead:

```
IF(K(XPOS, YPOS).NE.1) THEN
    K(XPOS,YPOS) = 1
ELSE
    GOTO 15
END IF
```

Comment: Oh this makes more sense, I see what I was doing now! Would there be any way to do this IF statement without the END IF?

Comment: I think the `END IF` is required in Fortran: https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/else-if.html

Answer (score 0):

This method is horribly inefficient. I'd do it something like the below. Note i've filled with i rather than 1, partially to show the random order of filling, partially to act as a check I haven't screwed up, as each number should appear exactly once.

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat random_fill.f90
Program random_fill

  Implicit None
  
  Integer, Parameter :: n = 5

  Integer, Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ) :: K

  Call fillarray( k, n )

  Write( *, '( 5( 5( i2, 1x ) / ) )' ) K 

Contains

  Subroutine fillarray( k, n )
  
    Implicit None

    Integer                       , Intent( In    ) :: n
    Integer, Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent(   Out ) :: K

    Integer, Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: index_list

    Real :: rand

    Integer :: val, x, y
    Integer :: i
    
    index_list = [ ( i, i = 0, n * n - 1 ) ]

    Do i = 1, n * n
       Call Random_number( rand )
       val = 1 + Int( rand * Size( index_list ) )
       x   = 1 + index_list( val ) / n
       y   = 1 + Mod( index_list( val ), n )
       K( x, y ) = i
       index_list = [ index_list( :val - 1 ), index_list( val + 1: ) ]
    End Do

  End Subroutine fillarray
    
End Program random_fill
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -O -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fcheck=all -std=f2008 random_fill.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
11  8 14 24 16
19 23 25 15  3
21 20  5  7 18
 6 17 22 12  9
 2  4  1 10 13

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
24 15  7 22 25
 8 17 10  1 14
 9  5  4 12  2
11 21 20  3 18
 6 19 23 13 16

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
22 11  6 21 24
 7  3  8 10 25
17 19 16  2  9
13  4 15  5 23
12  1 14 20 18
```

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck in an infinite loop because the statement `goto 15` is always executed.

- If `k(xpos, ypos)` is `1` then the first `if` statement is false, but the second is true so the `goto 15` is executed.
- If instead `k(xpos, ypos)` is not `1` then the first `if` statement is true, and so `k(xpos, ypos)` is set to `1`. The second `if` statement is only evaluated after this, and so is true, and so the `goto 15` is executed.

As other answers have mentioned, the method you are using is horribly inefficient. However, if you still want to use it, here is the fixed code, with a number of modernisations:

```
subroutine fillarray(k, n)
  implicit none
  
  integer, intent(in)    :: n
  integer, intent(inout) :: k(n,n)
  
  real(dp) :: x, y
  integer  :: xpos, ypos
  integer  :: i
  
  i=1
  do while (i<=100)
    call random_number(x)
    call random_number(y)
    xpos = 20*x + 1.0_dp
    ypos = 20*y + 1.0_dp
    
    if (k(xpos, ypos)/=1) then
      k(xpos, ypos) = 1
      i = i+1
    endif
  enddo
end subroutine
```

Note that this assumes that the array `k` has already been initialised, otherwise checking the contents of the array will lead to undefined behaviour.

As to whether `end if` is optional or not. No, it is not optional. It is always required. All languages need to know where the end of a loop is. C uses `}`, Python uses un-indentation, Fortran uses `endif`.